# Why does Create table show ORA-00957: duplicate column name

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Does anyone know why this select statement on this query runs just fine but when i add cte as in front of the same select statement it gives this error:

> SQL Error: ORA-00957: duplicate column name)

```
CREATE TABLE t1 AS 
SELECT * 
 FROM NS_F3 
 LEFT JOIN NS_FA2 
 ON NS_F3.PI_CANDIDATE_NUM = NS_FA2.PI_CANDIDATE_NUM 
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(NS_F3.TITLE, 'intern($|ship|[^a-z])', 'i');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because tables `NS_F3` and `NS_FA2` contain columns with the same name - in that case, you should use column **alias** to avoid duplicate column names.

Here's an example: I'm creating a *simple* table, as extract of several columns from Scott's `EMP` table:

```
SQL> create table t_first as select deptno, empno, ename from emp where rownum < 5;

Table created.
```

Join it to `DEPT` table:

```
SQL> select * from t_first e join dept d on e.deptno = d.deptno;

    DEPTNO      EMPNO ENAME          DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -------------- -------------
        20       7369 SMITH              20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        20       7566 JONES              20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30       7521 WARD               30 SALES          CHICAGO
        30       7499 ALLEN              30 SALES          CHICAGO
 ^^^^^^^^^                         ^^^^^^^^
 this is DEPTNO column ...         ... and here's another one
```

As long as it works in `SELECT`, it won't work in `CREATE TABLE`:

```
SQL> create table test as
  2  select * from t_first e join dept d on e.deptno = d.deptno;
select * from t_first e join dept d on e.deptno = d.deptno
       *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00957: duplicate column name
```

The solution is to use a column alias, such as:

```
SQL> create table test as
  2  select e.deptno emp_deptno,  --> first alias
  3    e.empno,
  4    e.ename,
  5    d.deptno,     dept_deptno  --> second alias
  6    d.dname,
  7    d.loc
  8  from t_first e join dept d on e.deptno = d.deptno;

Table created.

SQL> select * From test;

EMP_DEPTNO      EMPNO ENAME      DEPT_DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------- -------------- -------------
        20       7369 SMITH               20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        20       7566 JONES               20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30       7521 WARD                30 SALES          CHICAGO
        30       7499 ALLEN               30 SALES          CHICAGO

SQL>
```